# I am confused with comparing and jumping in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to input

```
11,00,01,10 in ebx and eax register.

Every time I input 01 or 10 I need to jump at l1.

And if I input 11 or 00 I want to quit from the procedure.
```

How can I do that? I tried it but only first two cmp's are working rest is not working.

```
    cmp ebx,0
    cmp eax,0
    je l1

    cmp ebx,1
    cmp eax,0
        jmp quit

    cmp ebx,1
    cmp eax,1
    jmp quit2

l1: mov edx,offset num3
    call writestring
    call crlf
    mov edx,offset num2
    call writestring
    call calf
```

Comment: I woul not recommend using mutliple cmp instructions in a chain. You are not enough in control of the flow of the program. Try to buffer one result , xor the appropriate register and issue cmp again in order to combine results and then proceed the desired logic

Comment: i don't know how to use buffer. My class didn't do buffer yet.

Comment: The simplest way to do several `cmp`'s combined together with logical AND operation[s] is to do the first `cmp`, then the conditional jump eg. to `my_label`, and then at `my_label:` do the second `cmp` and the relevant second conditional jump.

Comment: Fun fact: x86 has a "parity" flag, letting you branch on whether the number of set bits (in the low byte) of a result are odd or even.  i.e. a horizontal xor of the low byte.  `test eax,eax` / `jp`

Comment: Or you mean `11` => eax=1, ebx=1?  So you just need to check if EAX == EBX with one `cmp eax, ebx` / `je quit` else fall-through to the not-equal case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Are you sure about 'jmp'? shouldn't it be 'je'?
2. As far as I know, only the last cmp result is stored. So if you write two sequential cmp commands, the first one will not have any effect. You should check the result right after any cmp command.
3. If you jump right after checking the 10 case you'll never get to check the 11 case.

Comment: A little long but you can try to write the code as a simple algorithm (like in C) and convert it to assembly. For example: if (eax == 0) { if ebx == 0 { jump to l1 } else { quit; } } else { if (eax == 1) ... }

Comment: 2. yes, `cmp` simply writes its result to the FLAGS register, just like most other ALU instructions like `add`.  (Most other instructions *also* produce an integer result in a register, unlike cmp and test.)  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp vs. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add.